# Angular 2 reactive form verbose validation

Tags: forms, angular

When using Angular2 template driven forms we can use `#firstName="ngModel"` and then on the validation logic we can use the `firsName` like this `<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="firstName.errors.minlength">`

I'm trying something similiar but with reactive forms. The following code is working but it's too much verbose and prone to errors:

```
<input id="username"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"        
        [formControl]="form.controls['username']">    

<div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].touched && form.controls['username'].errors">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].hasError('required')">
        Username is required
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].hasError('minlength')">
        Username should have at least {{form.controls['username'].errors.minlength.requiredLength}} characters
    </div>   

    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].hasError('cannotContainSpace')">
        Username should not contain spaces
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is part of the component template. `form.controls['username']` appears in too many places. Is there any way to simplify this? I tried declaring a local variable like `#userName='"form.controls['username']"` but it does not work.

-- UPDATE --

The component is defined in it's own .ts file with the FormGroup:

```
export class TestFormComponent implements OnInit
{
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            'username': ['', 
                         Validators.compose([
                                        Validators.required,
                                        Validators.minLength(3),
                                        UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace]),
                         UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique],
            'password': ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can define a variable in the component behind to hold that `FormControl`

Comment: @HarryNinh What would be the syntax? I tried `#variable="formControl"` but I get this error `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "formControl" ("
type="text" 
class="form-control" 
[ERROR ->]#control="formControl" 
[formControl]="form.controls['username']">`

Comment: Where did you define your `form`?

Comment: You have mentioned template driven form but it seems like model driven. As far as I know form controls are associated with model driven forms. Refer this for more clarification :-  http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Comment: @HarryNinh I updated the question to answer this

Comment: @user32 No, I mentioned template driven as an example, where you can create a local variable pointing to the underlying Angular Control associated with the html element. In the question I said that I'm trying to achieve the same but with reactive forms. I saw your link but that doesn't take validation into account, which is the reason I'm asking this, because there is too much repetition in the validation divs on the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a property in your `ts` file to hold of that `FormControl`:

```
usernameFc: FormControl;
//....
ngOnInit()
{
    this.usernameFc= this.fb.control('', 
                     Validators.compose([
                                    Validators.required,
                                    Validators.minLength(3),
                                    UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace]),
                     UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        'username': this.usernameFc,
        'password': ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

Then in your template, use `usernameFc` instead of `form.controls['username']`:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="usernameFc.hasError('required')">
    Username is required
</div>
```

However, as all your reference to the form control is for showing errors, I'd strongly recommend you to watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0). She's showing us to automate the process of producing and showing errors for this particular use case. Ideally after you have some boilerplate (that can be shared for all model-driven forms), you can have something like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="formError.required">
    {{formError.required}}
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="formError.minlength">
    {{formError.minlength}}
</div>   

<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="formError.cannotContainSpace">
    {{formError.cannotContainSpace}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, that approach is a lot better, working on converting my code right now...